# Run hidden .m file

Tags: matlab, hidden-files

I was wondering if it's possible to run *[hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)* `.m` files in MATLAB. Take the following MWE:

My working directory contains two files: `main.m` and `.foo.m` which is *hidden* (in Linux, hidden files are preceded by a `.`)

```
dir
 |
 +-- main.m
 +-- .foo.m (hidden)
```

The file `.foo.m` contains:

```
disp('bar');
```

And `main.m` contains a call to `.foo.m` via the [`run`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) command

```
run('.foo.m');
```

When I run `main.m`, MATLAB throws an error:

```
>> main
Error using run (line 61)
.foo.m not found.

Error in main (line 1)
run('.foo.m');
```

However if I run `ls -a` and `dir`, they both display the hidden file inside the directory:

```
>> ls -a
.  ..  .foo.m  main.m

>> dir

.       ..      .foo.m  main.m
```

So it seems that MATLAB cannot find hidden files by default (at least in Linux).

Is there a way to enable running hidden scripts or functions in MATLAB?

---

EDIT:

Just realized that putting a `.` at the beginning of the file violates MATLAB's file naming rules:

> Source: [Specify File Names](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/specify-file-names.html)
>
> "File names must start with a letter, and can contain letters, digits,
>   or underscores."

Comment: No such thing on Win OS.

Comment: What is the whole point of using hidden Matlab files anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already figured out you can not run m-files that don't conform to the naming convention.  Meaning the file can not start with a `.`

However, if your intention is just to limit access to the "hidden" file you could make it a private functions.  [See Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html)

> Private functions are useful when you want to limit the scope of a
>   function. You designate a function as private by storing it in a
>   subfolder with the name private. Then, the function is available only
>   to functions in the folder immediately above the private subfolder, or
>   to scripts called by the functions that reside in the parent folder.